# VueJS render component instances

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a list of child components that dynamically gets filled with component instances

```
data: function () {
      return {
        child_components: []
    }
}
```

I would like them to be rendered in the template as the list changes, this doesn't work:

```
<li v-for="c in child_components">
    {{c.$el}}
</li>
```

Is it possible to render the actual component instances? Because in the component templates there are inputs that change their data, and I would like to access that data from the child_components list.

Thank you

Comment: I'd require more insight into your code to judge what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is XY problem. You need to lift up the state to parent component, so it would be exactly in the place where it needs to be accessed.

Comment: Be more explicit so we can understand the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something. `child_components` is key of object, so we can't use it like that.

```html
data: {
  child_components: function () {
      return [
         { el: 'example' },
         { el2: 'example2' },
      ];
  }
}
```

```html
<li v-for="c in child_components">
    {{c.el}}
</li>
```